# Fails to npm install nanomsg

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, nanomsg

I try to install `nanomsg` on a linux machine so I do

> npm install nanomsg --python=python2.7

I use `--python=python2.7` option, because I have two different versions of python. However that command fails with this kind of error message

```
make: Entering directory `/qt_home/{my_username}/node_modules/nanomsg/build'
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/nanomsg/deps/nanomsg/src/aio/ctx.o
cc1: error: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-maybe-uninitialized"
make: *** [Release/obj.target/nanomsg/deps/nanomsg/src/aio/ctx.o] Error 1
make: Leaving directory `/qt_home/{my_username}/node_modules/nanomsg/build'
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:270:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:204:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 2.6.18-409.el5
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /qt_home/{my_username}/node_modules/nanomsg
gyp ERR! node -v v6.2.2
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! Linux 2.6.18-409.el5
npm ERR! argv "/bin/node" "/bin/npm" "install" "nanomsg" "--python=python2.7"
npm ERR! node v4.2.1
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.7
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! nanomsg@3.2.0 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the nanomsg@3.2.0 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the nanomsg package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls nanomsg
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /qt_home/{my_username}/npm-debug.log
```

I searched about this on the internet, but couldn't find anything helpful. I have found [this link](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/809) so far, but it didn't help me.

My `node js` version is 6.2.2 and `npm` version is 2.14.7.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried, using sudo for the install. Sometimes it requires it for certain parts.

```
sudo npm install nanomsg --python=python2.7
```

Also im not too familiar with Python but can you add the direct path instead of python2.7

```
sudo npm install nanomsg --python=/usr/bin/python2.7
```

Comment: Yes, I have tried with `sudo` and direct path of python2.7, but the result was the same.

Answer (score 0):

The error message

> cc1: error: unrecognized command line option
>   "-Wno-maybe-uninitialized"

indicate that your compiler doesnot support the option `-Wno-maybe-uninitialized`.

The compiler option use to build de nanomsg librairie are defined in  [linux.gypi](https://github.com/nickdesaulniers/node-nanomsg/blob/master/deps/linux.gypi).

```
'cflags': [
'-O3', '-Wall', '-Wextra', '-Wno-sign-compare', '-Wno-strict-aliasing',
'-Wno-unused', '-Wno-char-subscripts', '-Wno-maybe-uninitialized',
'-Wno-implicit-function-declaration', '-lpthread',
],
```

In order to use the `nanomsg` configure to build it according your compiler, you could proceed like this :

```
git clone https://github.com/nanomsg/nanomsg
cd nanomsg
./configure
cmake .
make 
sudo make install
sudo cp /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/naming.pc /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/libnaming.pc
```

Next you should be able to run :

```
npm install nanomsg --use_system_libnanomsg=true
```